# Docker golang busybox "no such file or directory" error

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, busybox, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm building a multistage Docker image of a golang microservice and I want to make it very thin using busybox as base image to run the final executable.
The image is correctly built, but when I run it I get this error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I'm working on my Ubuntu laptop, so this error has nothing to do with the Windows OS as many other questions report.

This is my image.

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.15.3 AS build-stage

RUN mkdir /build
ADD . /build/
WORKDIR /build

RUN go mod download
RUN go test ./...
RUN go build -o goapp .

# final stage
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /build/goapp /app/

CMD ["./goapp"]
```

A very simplified version of my project folder could be:

```
project
├── Dockerfile
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── other-packages
```

Comment: done but got the exact same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your app with `CGO_ENABLED=1` (this is Go's default setting for builds) - and transplanting that executable to a docker image where there is no compatible library support (`glibc`, `dns` resolver etc.).

To ensure your build does not rely on any external libraries - statically binding all dependencies - and can then be deployed to a `SCRATCH` docker image or `busybox` - disable `CGO` during your build phase:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o goapp .
```

Comment: after having applied your changes I get this: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c989081c12b1f7b2a976bbf0a6848d48a929550d104b5ca6238758b5651394bc/merged/goapp: no such file or directory

Comment: the `COPY` looks correct. Maybe something is up with your `docker` cache. Try adding the `--no-cache` to your `docker build` command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a difference between the libc of the two images.
As introduced in [description](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox?tab=description) of busybox image, there are several `libc variants`, which is distinguished by image tags.

The libc of `golang:1.15.3` is glibc (it is `FROM` the corresponding version of `debian:buster`), so you should use `busybox:glibc` on your final stage.

The default `busybox:latest` is using `uclibc`. They are incompatible. Check the sha256 digest of [`busybox:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/busybox/library/busybox/latest/images/sha256-c9249fdf56138f0d929e2080ae98ee9cb2946f71498fc1484288e6a935b5e5bc?context=explore) and [`busybox:uclibc`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/busybox/library/busybox/uclibc/images/sha256-c9249fdf56138f0d929e2080ae98ee9cb2946f71498fc1484288e6a935b5e5bc?context=explore).